# Is there any way to turn off shutter sound of camera in Android Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g3

I am using Motorola G3. After upgrading to Android Marshmallow I am not able to turn off camera's shutter sound. I searched and found it is the bug of android 6. Is there any way to turn of shutter sound of camera?

Comment: Note that this might be illegal depending on your jurisdiction.

Comment: For most android phones, the shutter sound is disabled while the phone is *silent*. Tried that?

Comment: Which variant? This is a noted in several (mostly non-US) variants, although regional laws may play into it (if xxx country makes shutter sound a legal requirement, and yyy country doesn't have that law but both are covered by the same firmware, the most restricted will win)